# How in Excel change the direction of numbers (from right (0) to left (100))?

Tags: excel, numbers, excel-formula

I have a line of numbers from 0 to 100. They follow each other like usual:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... and so on --> ... 100
```

But I need to change their direction from right to left, like this:

```
100 <-- and so on ... 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Is there some special tool for this operetion?

Each number is in its individual cell and horizontally: 1 in `[A1]`, 2 in `[B1]`, 3 in `[C1]`, and so on.

Comment: The whole line in one cell, or each number in an individual cell?

Comment: @Ste, yes, each number in an individual cell, edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is exaclty what you need, you can simply enter 100 in A1, 99 in B1, select the 2 cells and drag the formula to the right (by clicking on the little square at the bottom right of the selected range).

If your actual problem is a bit more complex and you need to sort the data in descending order, you could:

- transpose it to make it vertical (Copy / Paste Special and select transpose)
- sort the data set with the standard sorting feature
- transpose it again back to its original range

Comment: similar to autofill, you can use fill series tool on ribbon so you dont have to drag all the way out.

Comment: You could also sort the data using the option for Left to Right orientation.

Comment: @lori_m I believe this is only available in excel 2007+ and the op did not specify which version he is using.

Comment: @RossLarson I believe this is only available in excel 2007+ too.

Comment: @assylias while many of the "new" features in 2007 were merely moved to more accessible locations out of the god awful menus, it appears that the fill-series function in 2003 and prior was a right click while all cells were highlighted which is harder that just using fill handle. . That being said, your answer is a very good one (which is why I just added a comment as I thought yours should be accepted)

Comment: @assylias, The left-to-Right sort option has always been available (Sort columns instead of rows: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sort-a-range-HP005202954.aspx) but agree that the new menus do make these options more discoverable

Comment: @lori_m haha - I should scrutinize my excel 2003 a little more ;-) Thanks